# Why does specifying @Size(min = 1, max = 3) directly on field not override any @Size constraints declared by other annotations on that field?

Tags: java, annotations, bean-validation

I have the following Java annotation:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Size
@Constraint(validatedBy = {})
public @interface MyString {

    @OverridesAttribute(constraint = Size.class, name = "min")
    int min() default 4;

    @OverridesAttribute(constraint = Size.class, name = "max")
    int max() default Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    String message() default "{org.example.annotation.mystring}";
}
```

Which is applied to a field in a POJO:

```java
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
import org.example.annotation.MyString;

public class PersonMyString {

    @MyString
    public String firstName;
}
```

And the `PersonMyString` class is initialised and tested using:

```java
@Test
public void printViolatedConstraints() {
    PersonCitadelString person = new PersonCitadelString();
    person.firstName = "bob";

    Validator validator =
            Validation.byDefaultProvider()
                    .configure()
                    .messageInterpolator(new ParameterMessageInterpolator())
                    .buildValidatorFactory()
                    .getValidator();

    Set<ConstraintViolation<PersonCitadelString>> violations = validator.validate(person);

    System.err.println("--");
    for (ConstraintViolation<PersonCitadelString> violation : violations) {
        System.err.println(violation.getPropertyPath() + ": " + violation.getMessage());
    }
}
```

A violation message is printed:

```
firstName: size must be between 4 and 2147483647
```

Why is it that when I update my POJO to be:

```java
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;
import org.example.annotation.MyString;

public class PersonMyString {

    @MyString
    @Size(min = 1, max = 3) // <-- New line
    public String firstName;
}
```

The additional line is ignored and I end up with the same violation printed:

```
firstName: size must be between 4 and 2147483647
```

Does the `@Size(min = 1, max = 3)` not override what is set on nested annotations?

Comment: Seems to make sense to me. The `@MyString` annotation has its own size constraints, separate from the `@Size` annotation (even if it's implemented by meta-annotating it with `@Size`), and the `@MyString` constraints are being checked first. That's how I interpret the behavior, at least. But why are you adding that other `@Size` annotation? Shouldn't you just do `@MyString(min = 1, max = 3)`?